# Should I ever put validation in a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an instance where I will do certain validations on a resource but not another, where the two resources map to the same model.

In concrete, I have an export model which is linked to a competition and I build an export of all the users in that competition.  So naturally there will be a validation to ensure that there is a competition attached.  However, a client wants to also be able to build all of the user exports at a given time and have it work like the competition exports.

I plan on using two separate resources for that(routes, controllers) but a validation only makes sense on a per resource level.

Anyone have any thoughts wrt best practices?

Comment: So are the 2 described scenarios both read actions? Validations really only make sense on write actions.

Comment: I didn't really mention it but the validations are on creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, no. Your best solution would be to split responsibility of export variant into specific classes that carry out the behavior you want on a model. Psuedo code for example, just guessing at implementation here- and may need fettling:

```
class CompetitionExports
  self.abstract_class: true # order just include the relevent ActiveRecord modules
  MODEL = Export

  def initialize(id)
    @competition_export_id = id
  end

  def all
    return [] unless validate
    MODEL.where(id: competition_exports_id).joins(:users) #can pluck/ select what you want here
  end

  private
  attr_reader :competition_export_id
  def validate
    return true if MODEL.where(id: competiton_export_id).has_competition?
    self.errors.add(:competition, 'does not exist')
    false
  end
end

class UserExports
  self.abstract_class: true # order just include the relevent ActiveRecord modules
  MODEL = Export
  def initialize(id)
    @user_export_id = id
  end

  def all_at(date)
    return [] unless validate(date)
    MODEL.where(id: user_exports_id).joins(:users) #can pluck/ select what you want here
  end

  private
  attr_reader :user_export_id
  def validate(date)
    return true if MODEL.where(id: user_export_id, date: date).present? 
    self.errors.add(:user, "no users at #{date}")
    false
  end
end
```

So here, I have two resources that check the Export model for their own specific behavior, without actually interfering with the model itself. This keeps the business logic at the model level itself, without mixing it in with everything.

In the controller, you could then just instantiate the class you need at the time. So for all Competition users:

```
export = CompetitionExports.new(params[:id])
export.all
```

or users at specific date

```
export = UserExports.new(params[:id])
export.all_at(params[:date])
```

Both will run through their specific validations before processing the results.

Comment: Hrm...I think this makes sense. You may want to change your answer to better reflect the edits I made. Wrapping a validation within another object seems to make sense though.

Comment: My current answer still fits. Having independent resource routes/ controllers is probably the minimum implementation anyway, but in terms of the validation, this should be abstracted into independent classes at the model level anyway- never the controller. 

Ideally, all the controller should ever do is take information from the view and pass it to the model. It can make the decision on how to respond after the model layer has processed the information, but that's really all it should do. Hope this helps anyway- just an idea on how to split logic up. High cohesion, low coupling ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom validation or conditional validation in rails.

Refer below link

http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-lightweight-way-to-handle-different-validation-situations/

Hope it's help you.

Comment: The difference is actually dependent on the route by which the export is created.

Comment: Ohk then ,Jay's answer is better in your case